# How to find a "Four of a kind" in a deck of 5 cards in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a task in c++. The task is to find if there is a "Four of a kind" in a deck of 5 cards. What I decided to do was to just write "if statements", but I found out that by using only this method, I would have to write 16 statements which isn't really efficient and kind of obeys what programming is about. Is there any way that I can use less statements to finish the task? Using a loop is all I can think of, but I can't figure out how to.

This is the code that I tried to do, the if statement is where I found this problem.

the `x` represents the shape of the card, `y` represents the number of the card. I made the `card` in an array of 4 because it starts from 0 and that would be 5 cards. `FK` is the Four of a kind part which will be set to True if it is a Four of a kind, the other 3 is for other parts which also need to be finished in the homework, but this `FK` part is where I started and where I am stuck.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct card{
    char x,y;
};
struct deck{
    card a[4];
    int find(deck x){
        int FK,FH,S,SF;
        if(a[0].y == a[1].y == a[2].y == a[3].y or a[1].y == a[2].y == a[3].y == a[4].y or )

    }
};
```

Comment: It's better than no code :) It's still unclear though. What is `x`, and `y` in `card` representing? Why does `deck` have `4` cards? What is `FK`, `FH`, etc? Try writing the `if` version first anyway.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that, the `x` represents the shape of the card,`y` represents the number of the card. I made the `deck` in a array of 4 because it starts from 0 and that would be 5 cards. `FK` is the Four of a kind part which will be set to `True` if it is a Four of a kind, the other 3 is for other parts which also need to be finished in the homework, but this `FK` part is where I started and where I am stuck.

Comment: Again, edit the question, instead of adding a comment.

Comment: By "shape" of the card, you mean the suit (heart, spade, diamond, or club)? Why did you call that field `x` instead of `suit`? If you used meaningful names, you could spend less time explaining your code.

Comment: *"array of 4 because it starts from 0 and that would be 5 cards."* -- no, an array of 4 elements has 4 elements. Yes, the indices starts from 0, but they end at 3.

Answer (score 1):

One simple design is to add up the number of cards of each rank ("number") in the hand and then see if any of the counts is 4.

One way to count the cards per rank is to have an array of 13 counts, one per rank.  Initialize all the counts to zero, look at each card in the hand and add one to the count for that card's rank.  If you are representing ranks as numbers 0 through 12, you can use the rank as an array index; otherwise, you might have to do something to transform it to a number from ranging from 0 to 12.

I was originally thinking you would get all the counts and then see if one of them is 4.  However, @Jerry Jeremiah's code in the comments showed me that that's not necessary.  It will be a little more efficient to check each count after you add to it.  If it's 4, you know the hand contains four of a kind and you can stop counting.  (There will be at most only one more card to count.)  If you do that check, the process will end either with finding four of a kind or checking all the cards without finding four of a kind, so you will not need to look at all the counts.

Instead of an array of counts, you could use a map container from the standard library.  One of the comments shows some code for doing that.

Also, in an array declaration, you specify the number of elements, not the highest subscript, so for a five-card hand, you want `card a[5];`.

Comment: No, I would be brilliant enough to have an array of 13 counts, loop through the hand once, and add to the corresponding count for each card, or if I wanted to be really fancy, I would use a std::map.

Comment: What do you mean by "see any of the counts is 4"?

Comment: @CrispyBacon `card hand[5] = {....}; std::map<char, int> rank_count; for(card x : hand) if(++rank_count[x.rank] == 4) std::cout << "four of a kind = " << x.rank << "\n";`

Comment: That looks better. The additional details are probably useful to people with this question. *(By the way, you technically only need 2 counts: one for cards matching the first in the hand, and one for cards matching the second if the second does not match the first. I don't know if I like my logic for this, but I still find it an interesting observation.)*

Answer (score 1):

The following is a complete compileable example. All the code fragments collected together in given order form a valid C++ program.

You write about [objects (cards) that have two properties: rank and suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck). Yet you call these properties `x` and `y` - that's terrible. Code should document itself. Instead of telling us what `x` and `y` mean, just name them so that they describe themselves. Thus:

```
enum class Rank { Ace, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, Jack, Queen, King };
enum class Suit { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades };

struct Card {
  Rank rank;
  Suit suit;
};
```

We can now define the stream output operators to make it easy to output those types e.g. to the console or to a text file:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Rank rank) {
    switch (rank) {
        case Rank::Ace: return os << "A";
        case Rank::_2:
        case Rank::_3:
        case Rank::_4:
        case Rank::_5:
        case Rank::_6:
        case Rank::_7:
        case Rank::_8:
        case Rank::_9: return os << char('2' + int(rank) - int(Rank::_2));
        case Rank::_10: return os << "10";
        case Rank::Jack: return os << "J";
        case Rank::Queen: return os << "Q";
        case Rank::King: return os << "K";
        default: return os;
    }
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Suit suit) {
    switch (suit) {
        case Suit::Clubs: return os << "♣";
        case Suit::Diamonds: return os << "♦";
        case Suit::Hearts: return os << "♥";
        case Suit::Spades: return os << "♠"; 
        default: return os;
    }
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Card card) {
    return os << card.rank << card.suit;
}
```

Now we can form a hand out of such cards - we perhaps don't need to limit it to exactly 5 cards. We can make our algorithms work for any number of cards in a hand, easily. We can also define a stream output operator that will output the hand to a stream:

```
#include <vector>

using Hand = std::vector<Card>;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Hand &hand) {
    bool first = true;
    for (auto &card : hand)
    {
        if (!first) os << ',';
        os << card;
        first = false;
    }
    return os;
}
```

At this point we have a type `Hand` that describes a hand. This is a common English term related to card games, and means a collection of cards in your hand. If you have 5 cards, you can call them a hand with 5 cards. The exact type useful for a `Hand` depends somewhat on the specifics of the game. Here we use the most generic type: a vector. This allows cards to come from more than one deck, i.e. the same rank and suit can be repeated. This will work as expected if all the cards come from just one deck: then there won't be any repeats since none are present in the source deck, and thus the `std::vector` will behave more or less like `std::set` would - a given card can either be present in a hand, or not present - but it won't be present more than once.

Four of a kind then means that there will be 4 cards that have the same rank, but different suits. There are many ways to write such code, but one way is:

1. For each rank you find in the hand, create a set of suits you found with that rank.
2. Once you've gone over all the cards in the hand, check if any of the ranks has all four possible suits in them. If yes, then you've got four suits of a given kind (rank). Otherwise, the answer is no.

The code is quite simple then - note how its form follows a high-level description in English. You can see that it looks quite different than what you proposed. That's how high level code might well look - you're describing what's being done at a much higher level.

The `std::set` does some of "the magic": it acts just like a mathematical set, where any particular object can either be in it or not be (there's no notion of being in a set "more than once"). You can't add the same element multiple times - adding it once or a thousand times has the same effect: the element becomes a member of the set, precisely once. Otherwise it's not a member of the set. Thus, all that we need to do to check if there are 4 different suits in a set is to just check if there are 4 elements in the set. Due to how the set works, if it has 4 elements (or any number of elements, really), those elements are all different from each other. This property of the set captures our requirements and allows us not to have to write low-level code.

We use simple primitives that capture our requirements. They give us vocabulary to express complex behaviors in terms of simple, universal yet powerful primitives. The basic properties of a set we depend on here are ordinarily taught in early elementary level mathematics (sometime in grades K-4). It can hardly get any simpler than leveraging what you've been taught when you were 9 years old - even though at that time they probably didn't say that they're teaching about `std::set` :)

```
#include <map>
#include <set>

bool hasFourOfAKind(const Hand &hand)
{
  std::cout << "Checking hand " << hand << " for four-of-a-kind\n";

  // Go over each card and collect its rank and add its suit to the set
  // of suits of a given rank.
  std::map<Rank, std::set<Suit>> ranksAndSuits;
  for (auto &card : hand)
    ranksAndSuits[card.rank].insert(card.suit);

  // Go over each rank and its associated set of suits, and find at least
  // one with four different suits.
  for (auto const &rank_suits : ranksAndSuits)
  {
    auto rank = rank_suits.first;
    auto &suits = rank_suits.second;
    if (suits.size() == 4) {
      std::cout << "Got four " << rank << " of a kind\n";
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now we'd like a test case that demonstrates that the code maybe works:

```
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    Hand straightFlush{
        {Rank::Queen, Suit::Hearts},
        {Rank::Jack, Suit::Hearts},
        {Rank::_10, Suit::Hearts},
        {Rank::_9, Suit::Hearts},
        {Rank::_8, Suit::Hearts}};

    Hand fourOfAKind{
        {Rank::Queen, Suit::Hearts},
        {Rank::Ace, Suit::Diamonds},
        {Rank::Queen, Suit::Spades},
        {Rank::Queen, Suit::Clubs},
        {Rank::Queen, Suit::Diamonds}
    };
    assert(!hasFourOfAKind(straightFlush));
    assert(hasFourOfAKind(fourOfAKind));
}
```

This concludes the complete compileable example.

Output:

```
Checking hand Q♥,J♥,10♥,9♥,8♥ for four-of-a-kind
Checking hand Q♥,A♦,Q♠,Q♣,Q♦ for four-of-a-kind
Got four Q of a kind
```